# Captured variable instantiating problem

Tags: c#, lambda, captured-variable

I'm currently musing about some idea I can't get right.

The problem is that I want to use one lambda function to instantiate a captured variable and another lambda to access a property of that variable.

Since the instantiating happens within the lambda the variable isn't actually instantiated the time I want to use it within the second lambda.. this is kind of a chicken and egg problem.

I know that the variable *will be* instantiated the time it's used in the second lambda but the compiler doesn't.

Is there any way my idea could work? Here's the actual code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;

        using (new DisposableComposite(
            () => cmd = new SqlCommand(),
            () => cmd.Connection)) // <- compiler error - variable not instantiated
        {
            // code
        }
    }
}

class DisposableComposite : IDisposable
{
    private List<IDisposable> _disposables = new List<IDisposable>();

    public DisposableComposite(params Func<IDisposable>[] disposableFuncs)
    {
        // ensure the code is actually executed
        foreach (var func in disposableFuncs)
        {
            IDisposable obj = func.Invoke();
            _disposables.Add(obj);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var disposable in _disposables)
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean just adding:

```
SqlCommand cmd = null;
```

(which solves the "definite assignment" glitch; it *is* definitely assigned... a null ;-p We then update the value before it is used).

IMO, though, you'd do better with nested `using` statements... and it isn't clear (from the code) where the actual connection is going to come from...

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
using(var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Damn.. that was an easy one. I guess I need another coffee. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can only avoid this by setting cmd to null before the using block:

```
    SqlCommand cmd=null;

    using (new DisposableComposite(
        () => cmd = new SqlCommand(),
        () => cmd.Connection)) // <- compiler error - variable not instantiated
    {
        // code
    }
```

Comment: ...but will this not lead to cmd.Connection throwing a NullReferenceException? Will that Func delegate "see" the instantiated cmd variable?

Comment: It won't throw an exception, because the assignment in the first delegate will happen first. The delegate will see the variable because of "closures", but that's something that can't be explained in a short comment :)

Comment: @Fredrik: Here's the definition of a captured outer variable: http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_14.5.15.3.1_Captured_outer_variables

Comment: Yes, the background of my comment is that I ran a similar test, but it was using strings. That was a bad choice, since they are immutable, which leads to completely different results. Thanks for putting my head back on :)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Marc that this does not really feel right.

Another option would be to define a new Context type object, that on Dispose disposes all the objects it provides.

Eg.

```
using (var ctx = GetContext()) {
   var cmd = ctx.CreateCommand();
   cmd.Connection = ctx.CreateConnection();
}
// cmd is Disposed 
// cmd.Connection is Disposed
```

Comment: Yeah.. this code was inspired by another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/966086/using-various-types-in-a-using-statement-c/) and I was just playing around and looking for a better way. I'm not saying that it's actually a better way.